# Is it better to return a generic JSON from an API and map your data structure in Javascript or return already mapped data structure from the backend?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, api-design

So looking for best practice advice.

I have a model on the back end and a component to display my data on the front end.  The component requires data in a different format than my model returns it.

Is it better to map the data on the backend and make it available in an endpoint ready to use in the component?  Or better to send some generic data format out the  endpoint and map in javascript before using in the component?

Comment: Returning a more generic structure potentially provides more flexibility (different front-ends/mobile apps/etc) without modifying your serverside code.

Comment: I don't think there's a single best practice. It depends on how closely tied the API is to a specific application.

Comment: I'm making the  application :)  I guess leaving it more generic opens the door to more possibilities.

Comment: dealers choice, but if one proxies the other ti will be slower.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance yall.